# wordpress - htaccess password directory affects all pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, password-protection

I trying to password protect a specific folder under the wp main root directory...
what happens here is that the pop-up password appears on all pages of my website.

the main htaccess is the wp default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the htaccess on my specific folder is:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "whatever-name-here"
AuthUserFile "path-to-my-passwd"
require valid-user
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<Files /PathToDirectory/*>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "whatever-name-here"
AuthUserFile "path-to-my-passwd"
require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: Thank you Richard...but it doesn't works. I mean with the above code,
the pass popup doesn't appears anymore.

Comment: If can be helpful, this problem occurs because in the password protected directory there is a tracking script that interacts with every page, so IMHO every page you visit it's like to access at the "pass protected directory".
I say this because disabling the script (..that automatically place its code in every page) the problem doesn't appears.

Am I wrong?...any ideas?